# How do you apply blur to specific meshes in Three.JS?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Yo! I want to apply blur to specific meshes in Three.js. I've followed this example/tutorial here: http://www.airtightinteractive.com/demos/js/shaders/preview/

but that's for applying shaders to the whole screen.

How do make one mesh blurry and another one clear?

Comment: You have to render that mesh to an offscreen buffer, blur that, then composite it with the rest of the screen. You *may* be able to expand (scale) the mesh very carefully and draw it using a blur shader, but that will be tricky. Look into Crytek's whitepaper on motion blur.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547921/three-js-apply-shader-to-blur-a-geometry

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Three.js - apply shader to blur a geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547921/three-js-apply-shader-to-blur-a-geometry)